# CryptoLicensing - Actication Limit bug in 2012..Net version

Tags: cryptolicensing

I just tried the new version 2012.Net/ build 62119 I think there is a bug. E.g. Using "Activation: Limit when machines to = 1" without floating and try make 2 activations from to different machines - it pass! It should have return Activation fail on the second machine activation.

Ok, i had a look at SQL profiler trace and found this....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID,MachineCode FROM (SELECT ID,MachineCode,LeaseValidTill FROM LIC_Activation as UniqueActivations WHERE ID = @ID AND MachineCode <> @MachineCode AND LeaseValidTill > @CurrentDate AND activationContext = @activationContext) as UniqueActivations2) AS UniqueActivations3
```

If `@activationContext` is `NULL` then the expression `activationContext = @activationContext` will fail - always return 0 count....

Is there anybody that have experience same issue or is it me that do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**This was a regression bug which has been fixed in the latest build.**

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developers of CryptoLicensing.